# AngularJS typeahead select on blur

Tags: angularjs, typeahead

I'm using typeahead through in my AngularJS project and I would like to have it select the entry if I type the full value and click out of the field.

I've put together an example of what I mean

http://plnkr.co/edit/NI4DZSXofZWdQvz0Y0z0?p=preview

```
<input class='typeahead' type="text" sf-typeahead options="exampleOptions" datasets="numbersDataset" ng-model="selectedNumber">
```

If I type in 'two' and click on 'two' from the drop down then I get the full object {id: 2, name: 'two'}. This is good, if however I type 'two' and click to the next field without selecting is there a way to accept the top of the list on loss of focus on a text field?

Comment: Is it must use typeahead directive that you use in the example? If not, you can try angular-ui (officially from angularjs community). http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ . Their typeahead already support what you want.

Comment: @map7 wondering if my solution works for you because I did leave it  somewhat generic.

Comment: @bhantol It looks like what I'm after, I like the example. I'm just trying to test this solution on my large app

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, I did try all of them out and settled with Mike answer as it best suits my purpose and the example really helped. I also like the fact that it only works if the user types the whole number and then clicks off focus. This way I think it doesn't confuse the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm with EnigmaRM in that ngBlur seems to be the way to do what you want. However, I agree with the others that this could be somewhat strange for the end users. My implementation is below ([and in plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/JpiHvnjeEEyzM2gU1JO6?p=preview)). Note that I trigger on ngBlur, but only apply the model if and only if there is only one match from Bloodhound and the match is exact. I think this is probably the best of both worlds, and hope it should give you enough to go on.

```
$scope.validateValue = function() {
  typedValue = $scope.selectedNumber;
  if(typedValue.num !== undefined && typedValue.num !== null)
  {
    return;
  }
  numbers.get(typedValue, function(suggestions) {
    if(suggestions.length == 1 && suggestions[0].num === typedValue) {
      $scope.selectedNumber = suggestions[0];
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I'd want to have that sort of functionality in my app. The user hasn't actually selected anything. So selecting something for them would introduce frustrations.

But I do understand that often odd requirements are needed. In this case, I'd attack it using [`ngBlur`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur). Assign a function to be called on blur. You can grab the contents of ng-model and then loop through your data (assuming static & not being sent via server) to find a match.

You can most likely just look at the source code of your typeahead directive and strip out the part does the comparison and then choose the first item in the array.

Comment: Just ngBlur won't work because by the time ngBlur occurs all the suggestions are actually vanished. There will be no time to catch the existing suggestions without firing another query on the suggestion engine.

Comment: I understand your point @bhantol. Never suggested that he would be able to access the suggestions. Not sure if you read through my post entirely. He'd have to grab the user input, and then loop through his data to find a match himself.

Comment: Try http://plnkr.co/edit/t2ohPy?p=preview - the full value is not available from the input. e.g. when typing 't' you will get 't' as you should. Typeahead does not put the first suggestion 'two' as a value.  About ngBlur - I should have mentioned in my comment that Typeahead also implements blurred event handler. The full value ('two') is not committed to the field. And when that happens the inputs value is merely "t" not "two".

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the underlying component does not emit any events for this condition. This will make the solution more complex. However when the value is being entered and the Typehead magic has happened you can supplement those events and catch them to update your ngModel.

I have created a plnkr based on your plnkr and although have not cleaned up but it is a working  [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/GqM1me?p=preview) doing by far what you need.

The gist of this is following code however you can put this code wherever best suited
The explanation below:

```
          //Crux - this gets you the Typeahead object 
          var typeahead = element.data('ttTypeahead');              

          //This gets you the first
          var datum = typeahead.dropdown.getDatumForTopSuggestion();

          if (datum){
            //you can do lot of things here however 
            //..I tried to - fill in the functionality best suited to be provided by Typeahead
            //for your use case. In future if Typeahead gets this 
            //..feature you could remove this code
            typeahead.eventBus.trigger("hasselections", datum.raw, datum.datasetName);
          }
```

In the above code you can also save the datum somewhere in the scope for doing whatever you like with it later. This is essentially your object `{num: 'Six'}` Then you may also use ngBlur to set it somewhere (however the plnkr I created doe snot need these gimmicks.)

Then further down - ngModel's value is set as below

```
   element.bind('typeahead:hasselections', function(object, suggestion, dataset) {
      $timeout(function(){
        ngModel.$setViewValue(suggestion);
      }, 1);
      //scope.$emit('typeahead:hasselections', suggestion, dataset);
    });
```

Comment: One of the reason as to why we may need similar functionality is to provide analytic/intelligence regarding the top suggestion that came up.